# Spark jobs failing with error Shutdown hook called before final status was reported

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Recently migrated the Spark version from 2.4 to 3.2.1 after that some of the jobs especially long running jobs giving below error and we fine tuned all the spark configurations but still unable to resolve the issue and i found some of the previous post mentioning that below error comes especially when data intensive jobs running in client mode but in our case all jobs running in cluster mode any tips or suggestions

```
24/02/15 14:14:39 INFO Client: Application report for application_1707932596261_1053 (state: FINISHED)
24/02/15 14:14:39 INFO Client: 
     client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service:  }
     diagnostics: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.
     ApplicationMaster host: qab01wn0.sbn1010026024qa.com
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 23671
     queue: default
     start time: 1708006450401
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://qaserver.sbn1010026024qa:8088/proxy/application_1707932596261_1053/
     user: spark
24/02/15 14:14:39 ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1707932596261_1053 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1677)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:955)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
24/02/15 14:14:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/02/15 14:14:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-98e785bd-9a24-4ac2-99f6-00794d74a773
24/02/15 14:14:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-9a84a0b2-8196-4bc6-a123-ca53ca30a916
```

Comment: could be several things such as:
- check cluster logs to see if it is OOM issue or a network issue.
- check if your code is compatible with spark 3.2, as there are differences from spark 2

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue when i took logs using yarn logs -applicationId and i found the error was due to loss of container while executing the task.